# Laravel many to many that match all data from array

Tags: php, database, laravel, relationship

I have products which have a many to many relationship with filters
The user may choose multiple filters and I want to display all products that match the selected filters. But by matching them I mean containing all of them (not only some of them). Here's an example to explain what I mean, let's say that the user is on the cars category page and he wants to filter all cars that are from year 2013 AND have 4x4. Now if the user selects those filters it will show all the cars that are from year 2013 OR have 4x4.
Here's my code in the controller:

```
public function showFilteredProducts(Request $request)
{
   $products = collect([]);

   $this->request = $request;
   foreach ($request->filters as $filter_id => $active) {
      $this->filter_id = $filter_id;
      $queriedProducts = Product::whereHas('filters', function($query) {
         $query->where('filters.id', $this->filter_id);
      })
      ->whereHas('category', function($query) {
         $query->where('slug', $this->request->category_slug);
      })
      ->get();  

      foreach ($queriedProducts as $product) {
         if (!$products->contains($product)) {
            $products[] = $product;
         }
       }
   }

   return response()->json($products->chunk(3));
}
```

As i explained this now returns the products if they match only one of the filters, but I want them to match all of them.

Comment: You should replace `$query->where('filters.id', );` with `$query->where('filters.id', $this->filter_id);` or is it just a typo ?

Comment: It is a typo, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public function showFilteredProducts(Request $request)
{
    $filters = $request->filters;
    $query = Product::query();

    foreach ($filters as $filter_id => $active) {
        $query = $query->whereHas('filters', function($query) use ($filter_id) {
            $query->where('filters.id', $filter_id);
        });
    }

    $query = $query->whereHas('category', function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('slug', $request->category_slug);
    })

    $products = $query->get();  

    return $products->chunk(3);
}
```

alternatively, based on your previous code, you can use `array_intersect` like this:

```
public function showFilteredProducts(Request $request)
{
    $products = collect([]);

    $this->request = $request;
    foreach ($request->filters as $filter_id => $active) {
        $this->filter_id = $filter_id;
        $queriedProducts = Product::whereHas('filters', function($query) {
             $query->where('filters.id', );
        })
        ->whereHas('category', function($query) {
            $query->where('slug', $this->request->category_slug);
        })
        ->get();  

        $products = array_intersect($queriedProducts, $products);
    }

    return response()->json($products->chunk(3));
}
```

Comment: I tried the first solution but when I try to filter with more than one filter it returns 0 products.
I have a car with year 2015 and 4x4 and when I filter 4x4 it shows it, when I filter year 2015 it shows it too, but when I press both filters i shows nothing, the products are 0

Comment: @TheAngelM97 sorry my bad, I updated the first solution, it now dynamically add where has filter one by one

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `orWhereHas()` instead of `whereHas()` on the second table that you are checking against.